# Im trying to Implement a Mutex in FreeRTOS using arduino but my output isnt coming out right

Tags: c++, arduino, mutex, freertos

Here i defined the handles and task prototypes

```
void Task1(void *p);
void Task2(void *p);

TaskHandle_t Task1_handle;
TaskHandle_t Task2_handle;
SemaphoreHandle_t myMutex;
```

Here is the setup function with the task and mutex creation functions

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myMutex = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();
  if(myMutex == NULL)
  {
    Serial.println("Mutex cannot be created");
  }
  xTaskCreate(Task1, "Task 1", 100, NULL, 1, &Task1_handle);
  xTaskCreate(Task2, "Task 2", 100, NULL, 1, &Task2_handle);
  vTaskStartScheduler();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Here are the tasks i created

```
void Task1(void *p)
{
  (void) p;
  while(1)
  {
    xSemaphoreTake(myMutex, portMAX_DELAY);
    Serial.println("task 1");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      Serial.println(i);
      vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
    xSemaphoreGive(myMutex);
  }
}

void Task2(void *p)
{
  (void) p;
  while(1)
  {
    xSemaphoreTake(myMutex, portMAX_DELAY);
    Serial.println("task 2");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      Serial.println(i);
      vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
    xSemaphoreGive(myMutex);
  }
}
```

**This is my code so far, but i dont seem to be getting my second task on the serial monitor:**
[Serial Monitor Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwQyA.png)

Am i using the semaphore function wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The mutex is locked while the Task 1 is sleeping, so Task 2 can never get the mutex. The section that is guarded by the mutex should be as short as possible, for example:

```c
void Task1(void *p)
{
    (void)p;
    while (1) {
        xSemaphoreTake(myMutex, portMAX_DELAY);
        Serial.println("task 1");
        xSemaphoreGive(myMutex);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            xSemaphoreTake(myMutex, portMAX_DELAY);
            Serial.println(i);
            xSemaphoreGive(myMutex);
            vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        }
    }
}
```

Modify the Task 2 in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The first attempt at an answer is clearly faulty. From the original question, Averean is expecting a different outcome:

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGVXH.png)

There are, potentially, two issues with the original code from Averean:

1. The FreeRTOS scheduler is biased towards avoiding context switches. Rather than releasing the patient Task 2, it sticks with Task 1, giving it the semaphore that it has just given, even though Task 2 has been waiting ages. To persuade the scheduler to move on, I have introduced a 1 tick delay.
2. Also, care should be taken to avoid conflicts within the Arduino Serial library which won't have been written with shared access in mind. To address this, I have added calls to Serial.flush().

So, Task1 now looks like this...

```
void Task1(void *p) {
    (void) p;
    while(1) {
        xSemaphoreTake(myMutex, portMAX_DELAY);
        Serial.println("task 1");
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Serial.println(i);
            vTaskDelay(500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
            }
        Serial.flush();       // 2. Avoid confusing the Arduino library
        xSemaphoreGive(myMutex);
        vTaskDelay(1);        // 1. Allow the scheduler to switch task contexts
        }
    }
```

And Task2 looks very similar and the result is exactly as seen in the [Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGVXH.png)